# Can we say objects have attributes, states and behaviors?

Tags: object-oriented

I was reading through Oracle's introduction to OOP concepts and I came across this description:

> Real-world objects share two characteristics: They all have state and
>   behavior. Dogs have state (name, color, breed, hungry) and behavior
>   (barking, fetching, wagging tail). Software objects are conceptually
>   similar to real-world objects: they too consist of state and related
>   behavior.

My problem with that passage is that when describing *state* its mixes *attributes* there too. For instance, the name and color of a dog are its attributes, while it being hungry or thursty are its states.

So in my opinion it's more accurate to break the characteristics of objects into three parts: **attributes, states and behaviors**.

Sure, when translating this into a programming language I can see that the three-fold partition becomes a two-fold one, because both attributes and states will be stored into fields/variables, while behaviors will be store into methods/functions.

But conceptually speaking it makes more sense to have the 3 things separate.

Here's another example: consider a lamp. Saying that both the lamp size and whether or not it's turned on are states is a stretch in my opinion. The lamp size is an attribute, not a state, while it being turned on or off is a state.

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yeap, you're missing traits as a technique to simulate behaviour.

Comment: Take a look at this post, it may help: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/12/09/immutable-object-state-and-behavior.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right in that objects consist of attributes, states, and behavior, if you define attributes to mean non-changing characteristics of an instance. As a matter of fact, it is important to make this distinction, because there exist objects which contain *only* attributes, (in your sense,) and no state; they are called *immutable* and they are very useful in programming.

This three-part definition is indeed represented in programming languages, for example using the `final` keyword in Java or the `readonly` keyword in C# to denote instance data which may not change throughout the lifetime of the instance.

I have to add, though, that non-changing instance data are usually not called attributes. We tend to speak of them as 'final' or 'readonly' or 'constant data' depending on which language we are using. The proper term for them would be 'invariants', but then this word is not frequently used in this sense; it is more often used for other things.

Comment: Thinking it terms of non-changing and changing characteristics of an instance makes sense. And I am glad I wasn't that far off. Thanks!

Comment: Is the lamp's size during a manufacturing or assembly process going to be a state?

Comment: No, it is going to be an attribute. (In the OP's sense of the word.)

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between state and attributes therefore it's simpler to define state as being possibly mutable or immutable. While having (immutable) attribute and (mutable) state is not incorrect (and is in many sense equivalent), that distinction makes the definition more complex than necessary. Although IMO the term "state" is probably not the best term to describe the concept since "state" somehow implies that it is supposed to change, while the "state" -- as described in Oracle's article -- does not have that.

Comment: I think that the stance of people towards immutability is changing as the years go by; for those who understand its importance, there is a fundamental difference between mutable and immutable state, enough to warrant a different name.  May I recommend a very interesting reading? [Eric Lippert - Fabulous Adventures in Code - Immutability in C# Part One: Kinds of Immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx)

Comment: @MikeNakis: is the difference as fundamental as the difference between state and behavior? I guess no sane person would say yes to that question. The difference between mutable and immutable states is shallow compared to the difference between states and attributes.

Comment: @LieRyan Well, the difference is not as fundamental as the difference between state and behavior, but I do not think that there is any requirement for the difference to be at least as fundamental as XYZ in order for it to merit acknowledging. The OP started by speaking of "more accuracy" in the definition. I think that yes, making the distinction adds accuracy to the definition. It certainly does not remove accuracy from it.

Comment: @MikeNakis: describing the geometry of the planets when talking about how a certain galaxy interacts with other galaxies is unnecessarily precise, likewise, talking about mutability/immutability of states when talking about states vs behavior is unnecessarily precise. Yes, it's more accurate if you do include them, but then we could make the same argument about making distinction between private vs public methods, pure vs side-effect methods, or stored vs derived attribute. These distinctions are important, but in the current scale they're just muddying details.

Comment: @LieRyan I agree with Mike Nakis that this is an important idea that is becoming more mainstream but you are correct in that the author of this passage is not making that distinction.  Technical documentation is not post-modern literature.  It's important to understand what the author intended.  In this case attributes are simply a subclass of state.  I'm also not convinced that attributes implies immutable to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's more accurate to say objects have only two characteristics.  Taking Oracle's example:

> Dogs have state (name, color, breed, hungry) and behavior (barking, fetching, wagging tail). Software objects are conceptually similar to real-world objects: they too consist of state and related behavior.

The fact that the values (state) for name, color, breed, and hungry are *stored* in the object in attributes is an implementation detail.  You don't really need attributes at all.

If you're going to include attributes as a third characteristic, then you'd also have to include methods as a fourth, since (like state) behaviors of objects can change as well.  State and behavior are two abstract characteristics of objects.  Attributes and methods are concrete implementations of those concepts.

Comment: Does the fur color of a fox become a state because it changes in winter?

Comment: @JeffO Fur color also might change when it gets old, wet, dyed... any number of reasons.  It's not really a state just because it can change during the life of one object, but because different objects of the same type can have different values for that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

State is set of attributes and corresponding values, so from my point of view, you are not right (and you are creating unnecessary additional complexity to simple definition).

Answer (score 0):

We can classify things in innumerable ways and each classification would have no "right answer". There is a benefit to classifying things only if the classification leads to some deeper understanding or to improve communication. If your team prefers to use the terms attributes, states and functions and has good working definitions for these this will help improve internal communication but you need to be flexible when communicating outside this group.

The concepts "hungry" and "thirsty" can be derived from basic attributes (e.g. blood glucose, hydration level) so we could think of state as a meta-attribute that is derived from base attributes that we can cycle to True or False based on the state of relevant base attributes.  For the light example, we could think of the light as having the attributes `applied_voltage` and `resistance` and the functions `voltage_switch()` and `shine()`.  The `voltage_swich()` is then a function of some input (e.g. manual switch, light, timer, etc.) and `shine()` is a function of `applied_voltage` and `resistance`.  We could declare a meta-attribute called `light_state` that is either True or False to help mentally construct the object, but in the end these ideas are all just mental constructs that we use to organize our work.

Answer (score -2):

The state of an object is **encoded** in its attributes, either directly or indirectly. For instance, if you want your Dog to be thirsty, you can let it have a

```
private boolean thirsty;
```

Alternatively, you can let it have something like

```
private Date lastDrinkAt;
```

and conclude whether your instance of dog is thirsty by comparing the current time with the time it last drank something.

Either way, the state of your objects lies within its attributes.

Then there are classes that do not have attributes, mostly utility classes. But you usually don't want to create an instance of them either in this case.

For the sake of being able to reason about statements, scientists usually stick to the principle of minimality. I think that's why Oracle didn't mention state explicitly. It can be derived from the value of the attributes.

Comment: Oracle _did_ mention state explicitly; read the quote. And the OP is obviously using the word _attributes_ in the sense of _non-changing_ characteristics of an object, so he is not confusing them with state.

Comment: They're still characteristics - whether they are changing or, whether you call them "attributes" or "members". There's nothing else in the programming world to represent the state of an object besides its attributes.

Answer (score -3):

The real-world connections are misguided. Here's how I would teach it(c++ approach):

1. Computers support two different storage formats: data and code
2. data looks like bits 010101010101
3. code looks like asm instructions
4. data bits have two different values, it's either 0 or 1
5. data is abstracted to data types: int i=1; is just short notation to some bits 0000001
6. code will look like a function: int f(int a) { return a+a+a; } is short notation for some asm instructions
7. when you have several variables, you combine them to a struct: int a; float b; can be placed to a struct AB { int a; float b; };
8. when you combine some code pieces to it, you get a class: class ABf { int a; float b; float sum(float c) const { return a+b+c; } };
9. Then for data we have variable names which can be used to find the value:
      a+b+c
   to access the data.
10. And then we have normal function calls:
     int k = f(10);
    to access the asm instructions "stored" inside f-function.
11. Then there is object instances:
     ABf var;
12. And the member function calls:
     int k2 = var.sum(10.0);
13. functions have types int f(int);
14. member functions have types int ABf::sum(float);
15. There is this-pointer with type ABf*
16. variables like a and b and c are context dependent, if they're inside member function, they could mean this->b, or just b.
17. Member functions int ABf::sum(float c) is just short notation for int sum(ABf* this, float c);
18. the word "state" just means the same as data
19. the word "behaviour" just means the same as code
20. the word "attribute" just means the same as data.

So there isn't really anything different between state and attribute. It's just random collection of bits. It's just arbitrary distinction to separate them. Just need to know what it's alias for.